# Which is better for alljoyn application, Alljoyn Observer listener or About Listener + Session Listener

Tags: alljoyn

Which is better for alljoyn application, Alljoyn Observer listener or About Listener + Session Listener?
I am new to alljoyn, I see Observer takes care of session management and reduces the application overhead?  Is that correct, which is better approach? Please clarify.

Comment: Please specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Rabban, one of the use case is to control the light bulb (on/off, get/set its properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `Observers` you don't need to care about session management and definitely reduce your app's complexity. You only need to specify with Alljoyn interfaces you are interested on and the framework will automatically create proxy bus objects that implement at least the interfaces you specified.

Providing a listener through the `registerListener` method, you can be notified
when a new object is discovered or when the object has been lost.

With about listener registered to the bus attachment plus session listener you can achieve the same of the Observer, but you have a fine grained control over the connection against the remote object.

That said, the best approach depends on what you have to do. In any case, starting with `Observer` might have a smoother learning curve.

Comment: @Gilly make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your clean explanation.  When you say "starting with Observer might have a smoother learning curve.".  Will there be any use case that About listener can do but not by Observer?  I want to decide the method before proceeding application design.  I have write a sample test app with both About listener and Observer.  With About listener& Session Listener I had problem with the session lost notification.  I am facing problem with session lost, when i turn off device I didn't get session lost notification and it arrives only when I turn on the device.  With observer it works ...

Comment: ...Then with observer I see device lost / announce without any issue also I am able to control the device without any issue.  So before start proceeding the application design with observer I would like to decide the best.  The current use case i am testing is to control the light bulb (LIFX / Android bulb app - Luminarie).  Please give your suggestion, it may be too early for me to decide on the best method (observer / about listener).